# make running rule, but target is newer than prereq

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got an issue with make rebuilding a target even though the target is newer than the prerequisite.  It's kind of a weird build target used for hashing the output from another rule and publishing the result over scp, but it otherwise is pretty basic, with a single pattern target file matching a single pattern prerequisite file.

```
$(build)/%.published: $(build)/%.tgz
  $(eval name := $(shell basename $^ .tgz))
  $(eval ver := $(shell tar xzf $^ ./etc/os-release -O | grep ^VERSION= | sed -e s/.*=//))
  $(eval hash := $(shell md5sum $^ | cut -d" " -f1))
  scp $^ $(publish-host):$(publish-path)/$(name)-$(ver)-$(hash).tgz
  ssh $(publish-host) ln -nsf $(name)-$(ver)-$(hash).tgz $(publish-path)/$(name)-$(ver).tgz
  touch $@
```

Both the target `$(build)/%.published` and prerequisite `$(build)/%.tgz` are regular files.  I've ensured the target is newer in bash:

```
test build/foo.published -nt build/foo.tgz && echo newer || echo out of date
```

There are no relevant .PHONY declarations.  But whenever I run `make build/foo.published`, it rebuilds the .tgz file.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

make version is GNU Make 4.2.1

Comment: There's a way to make `make` explain why it decides to build a target. `-v`, `--trace`, or something like that.

Comment: Can you run these 3 commands `make build/foo.published; stat build/foo.published build/foo.tgz; make build/foo.published` and paste results ?

Comment: Well, for one thing you want to be using `$<` here everywhere, not `$^`.  For another thing, it's generally not a good idea to use `eval` and `shell` functions in a recipe.  However, none of those things help explain the behavior you're seeing so I recommend using `--trace` to see what make is doing.  If that doesn't help you can use `-d` for even more details.

Comment: _But whenever I run make `build/foo.published`, it rebuilds the `.tgz` file_. So the problem is probably that `foo.tgz` is itself out of date and must be rebuilt, which in turn forces make to rebuild `build/foo.published`. Do you have rules for `.tgz` files?